# UPDATE table using INNER JOIN - help!

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysql-error-1052

I want to update table 'tourneyteamsISF' fields 'pointsfavor' and 'pointscontra' from table 'tourneygamesISF' fiels 'op1score' and 'op2score' from a certain ID.

For example:

```
Table name = tourneygamesISF 

op1(name of row) vs. op2    -  op1score = 25 - op2score =  20
```

I want to update this:

```
op1: (from: tourneygamesISF) = ID in tourneyteamsISF

+ pointsfavor = 25 (to: tourneyteamsISF)
+ pointscontra  = 20 (to: tourneyteamsISF)

op2: (from: tourneygamesISF) = ID in tourneyteamsISF

+ pointsfavor = 20 (to: tourneyteamsISF)
+ pointscontra  = 25 (to: tourneyteamsISF)
```

I have the following until now

```
UPDATE tourneyteamsISF 
INNER JOIN tourneygamesISF g1 ON (tourneyteamsISF.ID = g1.op1)
INNER JOIN tourneygamesISF g2 ON (tourneyteamsISF.ID = g2.op2)
SET pointsfavor = pointsfavor 
  + IF(g1.op1score > g1.op2score, g1.op1score - g1.op2score, 0) 
  + IF(g2.op2score > g2.op1score, g2.op2score - g2.op1score, 0)
, pointscontra = pointscontra 
  + IF(g1.op1score < g1.op2score, g1.op2score - g1.op1score, 0) 
  + IF(g2.op2score < g2.op1score, g2.op1score - g2.op2score, 0)
WHERE ID = 1;
```

But it gives the error: **Column 'ID' in where clause is ambiguous**

My tables are like this:

```
TABLE tourneyteamsISF
  ID integer autoincrement primary key,
  name varchar,
  pointsfavor integer,
  pointscontra integer

TABLE tourneygamesISF
  ID integer autoincrement primary key,
  op1 integer,
  op2 integer,
  op1score integer, /*score for team1*/
  op2score integer /*score for team2*/
```

I know that it has to do something with naming the id of table teams and games but I am stuck and confused. I will appreciate all the help I can get.

Answer (score 2):

`WHERE ID = 1;` <-  here is your problem.  Add the table name before it and it will compile without any problems.

eg.  `WHERE g1.ID = 1;`

This error is occuring because SQL cannot identify which `ID` column you want to use from the tables in your `SELECT` statment.

Comment: first of all..thnx....  with g1.ID it executes but it does not update 'pointsfavor' and 'pointscontra' from 'tourneyteamsISF' table... so it says affected rows: 0 .... it must be a problem with the ID... how can I identify it?

Comment: it still says affected rows 0 ... i dont know what is the problem.... help plz.... possible problems on inserting integers? or on the function?

Answer (score 1):

it has to be like this - WHERE g1.ID = 1